# Select record from one column which are not in another column

Tags: excel

Let's say I have 2 excel tabs (A) & (B):

TAB (A)

```
+----------+
|City      |
+----------+
| Seattle  | 
| New York | 
| Boston   | 
| Miami    |  
+----------+
```

TAB (B)

```
+------------+---------+
|City        | Name    | 
+------------+---------+
| Seattle    | Klay    | 
| Seattle    | Walis   | 
| New York   | Walis   | 
| Boston     | Klay    | 
| Miami      | John    | 
| New York   | Klay    |
+------------+---------+
```

I am trying to group them in order to obtain a new tab (result) where I have  the list of city where people NEVER went group by name:

TAB (RESULT)

```
+------------+---------+
|Name        | City    | 
+------------+---------+
| Klay       | Miami   |
|----------------------|
| Walis      | Boston  | 
|            | Miami   |
|----------------------|
| John       |Seattle  |
|            |New York |
|            |Boston   |
+------------+---------+
```

The only solution I came with was using a pivot table but I am looking for opposite result! I have also use Index & Match but it's not working.

Comment: So is this excel or msql/sql?

Comment: I am using Excel for this one ! But because I don't find a way to do solve this by using Excel I may use SQL

Answer (score 1):

Since you mentioned you are trying to do this in Excel, here's an Excel solution.  Let's pretend you have your data setup all in one tab, like so:

[image]

In cell G2 and copied over and down is this formula:

```
=IF(COLUMN(A2)>ROWS($A$2:$A$5)-COUNTIF($D$2:$D$7,$F2),"",INDEX($A$2:$A$5,MATCH(1,INDEX((COUNTIFS($D$2:$D$7,$F2,$C$2:$C$7,$A$2:$A$5)=0)*(COUNTIF($F2:F2,$A$2:$A$5)=0),),0)))
```

You can cut and paste each section to a different tab if desired.

Comment: It's working, thanks ! But can you explain me the magic behind this  formula ?

Answer (score 0):

Is this your desired ?

```
    SELECT NAME,
          CASE WHEN (SELECT 
          CITY 
          FROM TAB1)  NOT IN 
          CITY
         Then City
         END CASE  From Tab1 LEFT JOIN 
         TAB2 ON TAB1.CITY=Tab2.CITY
         GROUP BY NAME;
```

Answer (score 0):

in sql server it would be something like this

--tsql

```
with tableC  AS 
(
SELECT 
    a.City
    ,b.name
FROM tableA a
cross join (select distinct name from tableB) b
 )

SELECT 
    c.*
FROM tableC c
LEFT JOIN tableB b
    ON c.City = b.City
    AND c.name = b.name
WHERE b.city IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is indeed a MySQL problem, you need to get every combination of name and city, and then eliminate combinations that have visits.

```
SELECT bNames.Name, tableA.City
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Name FROM tableB) AS bNames 
CROSS JOIN tableA
WHERE (bNames.Name, tableA.City) NOT IN (SELECT Name, City FROM tableB)
ORDER BY bNames.Name, tableA.City
;
```

The result will not omit a repeated user name on successive entries, but that is something almost always better handled by post processing the results anyway.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution

```
Select b.name, a.city city_to_visit
From a join b on 1 = 1
Minus — some db use except
Select b.name, b.city city_visited
From b
```